# How to delete an object using reference in C++?

Tags: c++, object, reference

I have object ids and object references stored in a map.
I need to delete few objects whose references are in that map.
Using erase() function would just remove it from the map, but I would want the object to be deleted.

I'm trying to implement Garbage  Collection. I have a std::map root set map and std::map objects map. I'm trying to compare the object ids and references, which are there in the root set(or in the reference field of the objects in root set) and delete rest of the objects(using objects map) which are not part of root set.

Comment: It's not impossible that trying to `delete` through a reference will work, but it's usually a sign that you are doing something very wrong. 
Please share the relevant code to be sure that any answer to this question doesn't cause more problems than it causes.

Comment: We love that you're here and show us your code so we can help.

Comment: Sounds like a job for smart pointers but this is too little information to say for certain.  If the map is going to control the lifetimes, the map should own the objects.

Comment: How do you store the object references? What objects do they really reference? Where and how are the real objects stored? And can you please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: IIRC, references are not valid mapped types for maps.

Comment: Store objects in the map by value and that solves your issue.

Comment: The object has many parameters, so I can't just store the object by value